# How to return a result from a thread in Android Viewmodel?

Tags: android, android-room, android-viewmodel

I am trying to use viewmodel in my android application and I want to obtain an item based on its id . As referring to database has to de done in a thread , there is no option for me to return the item obtained to my activity through viewmodel.  Without viewmodel , I can directly invoke the thread from the activity and use the result obtained within the activity .

I dont want to use call backs . Also using livedata for obtaining a single item is not preferred .

The method and its associated dao call looks like this .

```
 @Query("SELECT *FROM Entity WHERE id=:id ")
public User getdatabyid(int id);
```

**This method is from viewmodel**

```
  public void getEntitybyid(final int id) {
    Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            database.dao().getdatabyid(id);  //how can I return the item obtained to my activity from here 
        }
    });
    thread.start();

}
```

I am calling this method from my activity like this

`User user=  viewModel.getEntitybyid(id);  // I want the above method to return the item here`

Is there any other way I can get the result . Thank you .

Comment: "Also using livedata for obtaining a single item is not preferred" -- why? "I dont want to use call backs ." -- well, then if you are also banning `LiveData`, your primary choices are to return a `Future`, adopt RxJava and return a `Single`, or adopt Kotlin+coroutines and use a `suspend` function.

Comment: Hi , I don't want to use livedata here because it is a single time use item and using livedata calls it multiple times when it changes .

Comment: It's almost as if you need some sort of mechanism for calling back to the activity when the result is ready. All constructs you could possibly write *are* that at some level.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment about LiveData, what do you mean?

Comment: Also spawning new threads like that can easily lead to performance hits as well as OutOfMemory errors. You might want to look into thread pools or more sophisticated background tasking APIs like Executors.